# How to reference/import and export in angular2

Tags: angular, import, reference, export

Does anyone know if importing classes with three slashes like this "/// " is valid in angular2 and when exactly it should be used? When should the import/export statements be used and when the the three-slashed reference? Thank you in advance.

Comment: /// is JavaScript and that is technically valid as a reference. For future proofing, tree-shaking, and other goodness that's in the pipe for ES6+ you really should be using the import {ModuleName} from ""; syntax and eschewing the old style reference system as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Import and export are the key word of typescript to import and export the modules. For example

```
export class MyModul {
// my module
} now you can import this module in other file like
import {MyModule} from './mymodule';
```

Angluar2 is built on typescript and has many modules. You simply import the module you want to work from angular2. 
Example

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core.
```

If you are using third party module in angular2 which are built on JavaScript then you have to use typings for that. For example if you want to use node for typescript then you have to install typed node with typings like this

```
typings install node
```

And when you will try to import any module from node like http and use that like http.get it will not recognize in that case you need to add reference where typings node is installed with three slashes and then typescript will recognize http and give you even nice intellisence . Hope it clears things and helps ylu to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help!